# android studio can't find strings define in build.gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, ide

I have define string in the app-level Gradle file like below

[image]

then I am using these strings in projects which shows a red text and when i am hover mouse over it then it shows

> Cannot resolve symbol 'Home_Banner_ID'

[image]

but when I run the project it works completely fine it didn't give me any build error or any crashes.

I think it's problem with android studio IDE
and these problems happen with only string define in the build.Gradle.

Comment: Tried `Clean Project` and `Rebuild Project` ?

Comment: I have already tried that but it's not working

Comment: i also tried Invalidate and restart option but still i get same problem

Comment: I think it's android Studio IDE problem

Comment: Which version of Android Studio?

Comment: the current version is Android Studio Arctic Fox 2020.3.1 but I am facing this problem last 3 or 4 android studio update

Comment: `buildTypes {
        release {
             resValue "string" ,"DYNAMIC_LINK_PREFIX","openslietrepository.page.link"
                 }
        debug{
  resValue "string" ,"DYNAMIC_LINK_PREFIX","slietrepositorydebug.page.link" 
        }
    }` It is working for me in the latest version of android studio and even in the last versions. Could you please confirm that have you declared `resValue` in both buildTypes?

Comment: still not working

Comment: Could you please confirm that have you declared `resValue` in both buildTypes?

Comment: add `defaultConfig {
        resValue "string", "APP_ID", "yOur value"
    }`